# Зависает форма при выполнении команды SSH C#

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, ssh

Когда я соединяюсь с сервером и выполняю команду через SSH C#,
у меня зависает форма. И «развисает» только после того, как команда выполнится.

Вот пример кода:

```
using (var client1 = new SshClient("IP", "PORT", "PASS"))
{
    client1.Connect();
    client1.RunCommand("yum update");
    client1.Disconnect();
}
```

Подскажите, что делать.

P.S. То, что надо сделать отдельный поток, я знаю. Вопрос в том, как это реализовать.

Comment: Вопрос в том, а что же надо делать, пока выполняются запросы. Если пользователь ещё и может запускать новые, то одна реализация, если форма на время запуска должна блокировать часть функций - то другая. И, реализация будет разная для winform\wpf.

Comment: Ничего запускать больше не надо будет, реализация на winform.

Answer (score 2):

Предположим, вы запускаете эту команду по клику кнопки. Тогда с использованием `async/await` это может выглядеть так:

```
public async void btnDoCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // чтобы пользователь не нажимал, пока выполняется команда
    btnDoCommand.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
        // запускаем в отдельном потоке
        await Task.Run(new Action(DoCommand));
        // оставшаяся часть метода будет выполнена после завершения работы DoCommand
    }
    catch (Exception) // тут перехватывайте нужный тип исключения
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Не удалось выполнить команду");
    }
    finally
    {
        btnDoCommand.Enabled = true; // кнопка снова доступна
    }
}

private void DoCommand()
{
    using (var client1 = new SshClient("IP", "PORT", "PASS"))
    {
        client1.Connect();
        client1.RunCommand("yum update");
        client1.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6d1HGOi.png - Вот такая ошибка.

Comment: @user199587 Кажется надо вот так `await Task.Run(new Action(DoCommand));`

Comment: @user199587 поправил ответ, player one прав.

Comment: Вот так тоже работает: `await Task.Run(() => DoCommand());` (обычно нужно передать в процедуру ещё и параметры, так что лямбда лишней не будет).

Comment: Спасибо, и ещё 1 вопросик, мне надо отключиться от сервера, как быть тут? То есть закрыть соединение с сервером, если команда ещё выполняется.

Comment: @user199587 вы имеете в виду, что вам нужно поддержать отмену выполнения команды?

Comment: Ну допустим у меня выполняется yum update, сервер будет обновляться минут 5 - 10, и я захотел прервать обновление, и отключиться от сервера.

Comment: @user199587 отключиться (выполнить `Disconnect`) можно, но вопрос в том, прервет ли это выполнение команды (обновления) на сервере?

Comment: В этом и проблема. :(

Comment: @user199587: Тогда сервер должен предоставлять возможность прервать бегущую команду. То есть, предоставить _другую_ команду, которая остановит уже выполняющуюся команду.

Comment: @user199587 это проблема выходит сильно за рамки текущего вопроса. Оформите новый, опишите, что и как у вас все работает (в т.ч. этот процесс обновления на сервере). Возможно можно сделать новую команду отмены, однако для этого сам процесс должен быть прерываем -- а это не всегда возможно.